# Print out even numbers between two given integers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How would I print out even numbers between two numbers?

I have a script where a user enters in two values and them two values are placed into their respective array elements. How would I print the even numbers between the two values?

Answer (score 3):

See `man seq`. You can use

```
seq first incr last
```

for example

```
seq 4 2 18
```

to print even numbers from 4 to 18 (inclusive)

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash.

```
printf '%s\n' {4..18..2}
```

Or a c-style for loop

for

```
for ((i=4;i<=18;i+=2)); do echo "$i"; done
```